# How to remove a specific line break between two lines in a string without removing other breaks ? php

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this and I want to remove the break of the line if the number in the line doesn't match the line number. How is it possible ?

It's my string :

```
1 //line1
2 //line2
3 //line3
5 //line4
4 //line5
5 //line6
6 //line7
```

For example in this string the line 4's value is 5 so I must omit its break and make it like

```
 1
 2
 3 5
 4
 5
 6
```

Here is my code :

```
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $string) as $line){
    if ($line != __LINE__){
        //remove the break and I'm stuck here...
    }
}
```

Any solution ? Thanks in advance...

**UPDATE** :
I've also tried converting it into an array like below :

```
$linesArray = explode("\n", $string);
foreach($linesArray as $key => $val){
    if(($key+1) != $val){
            $output[$key] =  $linesArray[$key-1].' '.$val.' '.$linesArray[$key+1];
            $o_line++;
    }else{
        $output[$key] = $val;
        $o_line++;      
    }
}
```

but it's not working or I'm wrong somewhere...

Comment: I may even need to remove breaks of 3 lines too... I'm just kind of stuck. :(

Comment: So your input string is _just_ those numbers, or are the `//lineX` “comments” included as well?

Comment: May be this line has issues - $output[$key] =  $linesArray[$key-1].' '.$val.' '.$linesArray[$key+1];       // as key is 0 for first iteration, so it will be like $linesArray[-1]

Comment: @CBroe No just those numbers... I wrote the comments to clearify the problem

Comment: @Nilesh I know what u mean but the first line never goes through that condition it always use the else statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a code for you. Let me know if it meets your goal.

```
$string = "1\n2\n3\n5\n4\n6\n5";
$line = explode("\n", $string);
$line2 = "";
$n = 1;
foreach($line as $v) {
    if($n != $v) continue;
    $line2 .= $v."\n";
    $n++;
}
echo $line2;
```

Comment: thanks for ur response... Clean code. There is just a problem. As I mentioned in my question  I need the continued line to be with the previous line. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this line has issues -
$output[$key] = $linesArray[$key-1].' '.$val.' '.$linesArray[$key+1];

// as key is 0 for first iteration, so it will be like $linesArray[-1]

Comment: Nope as I mentioned in the comments it's not the answer ==> comment : I know what u mean but the first line never goes through that condition it always use the else statement...